# Why does gUw keep cursor in same position but gUb moves it to the start of the word?

Tags: cursor-movement

For example: if my cursor is on `c` in `abcde` and I do `gUw` then the result is `abCDE` with the cursor on `C`, while `gUb` results in `ABcde` with the cursor on `A`. Is this the expected behaviour? It seems that these two should behave analogously, but they don't.

Edit: I should add that I'm using

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jan 10 2018 11:27:58)
macOS version
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`:h operator`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#operator):

> After applying the operator the cursor is mostly left at the start of the text
>   that was operated upon.  For example, "yfe" doesn't move the cursor, but "yFe"
>   moves the cursor leftwards to the "e" where the yank started.

You are experiencing the expected behavior: your cursor is put at the beginning of the text described by your motion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That definitely explains it. If my goal is to type a word, go into normal mode, capitalize it, and then continue inserting, is the best way to do `abcde <ESC> gUbw`? The reason I ask is that I'm trying to avoid use of the shift key because the repeated stretching irritates my hand, and i have caps lock rebound to ctrl.

Comment: @ira I would say that if you absolutely want to capitalize your word while you are writing that is you best bet. But I think you would be more productive if you wrote your sentence (or line of code) and then go to insert mode to change the capitalization: this way you create repeatable changes which are meaningful and make the dot command `.` more powerful :)